# Filtering BETWEEN string parameters

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008

I have a report with text parameters that represent Quarters and Years. For example, '1Q11' represents the 1st quarter of 2011, '2Q13' represents the 2nd quarter of 2013, and so on. I also have records that that have a field using this format, 'QuarterYear'.

The issue is, I need to incorporate this into a report, to have the data only display when the quarter and year is in between those specified in the parameter. For example, if a user selects '1Q12' and '4Q12', the report should display all records with a QuarterYear value of '1Q12','2Q12','3Q12', and '4Q12'. If the user selects '1Q12' and '2Q13', the report should display records with QuarterYear value of '1Q12','2Q12','3Q12','4Q12','1Q13', and '2Q13'.

It is difficult for me as these are not date values so I could not use a simple BETWEEN. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the data stored **on the table** as dates, or as text in the format nQyy (eg. 1Q12)?

Comment: You could use the `DateTime`(f.e. first date of that quarter) as value.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is all stored as varchar strings in the table.

Comment: Then you need a scalar valued function to calculate the date. However, that's really _unfortunate_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a relatively small table, the simplest way to do this might be to use string slicing - so your condition would be something like:

```
where ...
right(table_quarter,2)+left(table_quarter,1) >= right(@start,2) + left(@start,1) and
right(table_quarter,2)+left(table_quarter,1) <= right(@end,2) + left(@end,1) 
...
```

Note that this condition is non-sargable, ie. it won't be possible to use any indexes on your table's quarter-year column.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried parsing 1Q12 to a date, which in this case would become 01/01/2012 with ending date as 31/03/2012?

And when you select ranges like 1Q12 to 3Q12, then pick reports between 01/01/2012 to 30/09/2012.

Otherwise (not a recommended solution I'd say), you can write a simple function that can run in a loop to find all quarters in between the given range. And do something like increment month (increment year after month is 12, and reset month to 1) and keep going until it meets the end of range.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over how the string data is formatted, you should consider converting it to a format like 12Q3 instead of 3Q12 which will allow simple `BETWEEN` to work.  If you cannot control the format of that specific field, another option may be to add a calculated field to the table in this format based on the original field. `=right(QuarterYear,2)+'Q'+left(QuarterYear,1)`

In both cases, you can index the field to optimize the `BETWEEN`.  If neither of these are usable options, then Mark Bannister's solution is probably best.